# Spring JMS - Issue with Default Message Listener Container issues on setting both durable and shared subscription

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have developed a Spring Integration Application which is running in multiple instance of PCF.

The application listens to the topic and process the message.

I use `MqConnectionFactory` for Topic connection and Spring JMS - `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` for listener message.

On Durable Subscription - With Same Client ID.

The first instance of the application runs without any issue and process the message.
Other instance, I am getting the following Error.

```
2429 - MQRC_SUBSCRIPTION_IN_USE
```

When I have different Client ID , Every instance of the application get the same copy of message resulting in duplicate processing - The idea of running multiple instance is to share the load and process parallel.

On Enabling Shared Subscription along with Durable Subscription - With Same Client ID.

Every instance is getting the following error.
JMSWMQ2025 Failed to subscribe to the topic due to the exception occurred

```
reason '2432' MQRC_SUB_ALREADY_EXIST.
```

Comment: For a non-shared subscription you must have a different client ID and/or subscription name and as expected a copy of each published message will be delivered to each subscriber.  When you change it to a shared subscription you need to ensure you remove the original non-shared durable subscription, if you have not then the 2432 is expected. The state of a subscription being shared or non-shared is determined at the time it is created, once it is created it is resumed, so you can't switch to shared with out first removing the non-shared subscription.

Comment: Mvs does my comment describe the issue you face, if so I'll write up an answer with those details and a link to the description.

Comment: @JoshMc - I made the following changes and it started working without any issues. Didn't give the client id as it was optional as per the JMS 2.0 Documentation and set both durable shareable subscription to true. 
https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jms2messaging.html

Comment: Thank you for the feed back, but you did have to get rid of the prior subscription or change the subscription name to get around the `MQRC_SUB_ALREADY_EXIST` error right? Note if you didn't get rid of the prior sub and just changed the name, then likely you have a "orphan" subscription out there receiving messages with no consumer.